# ServiceStack original Request DTO after Filter manipulation

Tags: c#, servicestack

Good day, is there a way to get the original request DTO in the response filter.
In my request filter I manipulate the values of the DTO.

```
 appHost.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, reqDto) =>
        {
            if (reqDto is Granite.Webservice.Resources.MasterItemRequest)
            {
                string code = ((Granite.Webservice.Resources.MasterItemRequest)reqDto).Code;
                ((Granite.Webservice.Resources.MasterItemRequest)req.Dto).Code = code.Replace("^", "");
            }
        });
```

In the above code you can see I change the Code to exclude ^ character. Take note this is a example and not the actual implementation so don't ask why ^ is appearing.

Then in my response I would like to get the original value of the request and the property Code.

My response filter:

```
        appHost.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, reqDto) =>
        {
            var t = req.OriginalRequest;

        });
```

If I look at the req OriginalRequest it does not have the DTO. Also the request reflects the new values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a ServiceStack plugin which needs both request and response Dtos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333689/how-to-write-a-servicestack-plugin-which-needs-both-request-and-response-dtos)

Answer (score 2):

The `IRequest.OriginalRequest` and `IResponse.OriginalResponse` lets you get the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequestBase or HttpListenerRequest objects.

Instead you can get it from the `IRequest.Dto` property, e.g:

```
appHost.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, resDto) => {
    var dto = req.Dto;
});
```

Comment: The problem is the original request (example DTO: Item.Code = **some^thing** ) gets changed to ( DTO = Item.Code = **something** ) in my request filter. My request filter plugin removes the "^" character. In my response filter the DTO reflects the values that I have changed and not the original request from outside my API.

Comment: My question is, is it possible to get the original request in the response filter with the original values before the request filter changed it.

Comment: @FrancoisTaljaard No, ServiceStack doesn't create and maintain multiple DTO instances for each request. You can still look in Request.QueryString for the request params but if you want access the original request dto you'd need to store a clone of it yourself in Request.Items.

Comment: Thx, thats what I thought.

Comment: @FrancoisTaljaard You can still do the awkward way, as I've described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333689/how-to-write-a-servicestack-plugin-which-needs-both-request-and-response-dtos: Just store the original DTO in the items of the request, which you can later access.